# Is there a way to configure DEP from the command line or in the registry?

Tags: windows-server-2008, configuration, windows

I'd like to *exclude* a single application's executable from DEP (Data Execution Prevention) on our automated Windows Server 2008 builds. Is there a way to do this either as a registry setting or from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try editing the application path below and importing it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\MyApp.exe"="DisableNXShowUI"
```

**Edit:** Just checked on a Server 2008 install I have and that is how the Nagios client is handling the DEP issue with their installer.

Comment: Fab!....Did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is the [Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/cc507847.aspx). With this you can create a shim that specifies that DEP should be disabled for your application.